# How to translate "-ing" "caused something to happen" verbs?

Tags: grammaire, participe-présent

Here are some sentences I don't know how to translate.

> - 50% of the time, fixing one bug in one part of the code can cause other code that uses it to work differently, **creating** another bug. *(But the word "fixing" is not bolded; because I believe it's translated with an infinitive)*
> - I stepped on the slug, **squishing** it.
> - Scar blamed Simba for what had happened, **traumatizing** Simba.

These words seem to mean that something caused something to happen to another thing:

- "creating another bug": caused another bug to be created.
- "squishing it": caused it to be squished.
- "traumatizing Simba": caused Simba to be traumatized.

I'm thinking that *maybe* [causative faire](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/faire-causative/) might be used here, but I'm not sure.

What else I tried:
I thought the "-ing" ending of these words might give me a clue; but none of the present participle uses on [this](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-ii/french-ii-participles/present-participles) page mention the "causing something to happen" way these words are used; it isn't an English gerund; and I don't think it's the English present progressive form of a verb. So I don't even know what these words are, grammatically, in English, to help me learn how to translate them into French!

Comment: It can differs, but I'd usually use: gerund version (-ant), use the infinitive, or use the noun of the same word family: créant, créer, création in the first case. But it depends on which way you want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The present participle, same as your English versions, is what you want:

- 50% of the time, fixing one bug in one part of the code can cause other code that uses it to work differently, **creating** another bug.
  → 50% du temps, corriger un bug *(or **un bogue**)* dans une partie d’un programme provoque un changement de comportement d’autres parties qui utilisent la partie corrigée, **créant** un nouveau bug.
- I stepped on the slug, squishing it.
  → J’ai pilé sur une limace, l’**écrabouillant**.
- Scar blamed Simba for what had happened, **traumatizing** Simba.
  → Scar blâma Simba de ce qui était survenu, **traumatisant** ce dernier.

---

Two notes:

1) One may want to add *“de ce fait”* after the present participle. Not mandatory by any mean, but it may add emphasis on the action being accomplished

- créant de ce fait un nouveau bug.
- l’écrabouillant de ce fait.
- traumatisant de ce fait Simba.

2) In the third example, I believe using *Simba* a second time would usually be considered heavy and inelegant in French, unless we add *de ce fait* as in note 1. Otherwise, the two mentions are too close together.

Comment: unrelated, but I noticed you used the simple past for "Scar blamed Simba". can you tell me what "flavour" or "feeling" or "style" that using the simple past (vs the passé composé) has? or, what caused you to want to use the simple past for that?

Comment: @silph I simply thought I recognized the Lion King, and worked my way to the classic storytelling / narrative tense of French for the situation described. So no more reason than me thinking I was in an imaginary or fantasy world. The passé composé would have worked just as well, and would probably be more appropriate in a real life situation. Sorry for *[quiproquo](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/quiproquo)* :)

Comment: Isn't it a gérondif rather than a participe   présent ?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: I'm not sure if the same is true in French, but in English, there is a difference between a gerund and a present participle, though they look the same. http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm

Comment: @silph Yes there is a difference in French too. After reading a bit it seems to be a participe present in a proposition subordonnee circonstantielle.